# how to pass X and Y coordinates to the sever when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, servlets, button, submit, popover

I'm developing an Webpage and at one moment I get the X and Y coordinates of an click button over an image. I'd like to pass these values to my server when I hit a submit button.

When I click over the image, an popover is open. It has an input text and a submit button.

```
$('.ImgMapa').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        title: "<form action='adiciona'><input type='text' name='nome'/>"
            + "<button type='submit' id='saveStore' class='btn' value='Save'>Save</button></form>"
    })
```

I've declared my servlet and associate it with my form. I can send my input text String to my server normally. For that I'm using an HttpServlet class like this:

```
public class AddInfo extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name = request.getParameter("nome");
}
```

With that code, I can get the name value inserted on the popover. But how can I pass the X and Y coordinates also?

Obs.: I already have 2 javascript variables with X and Y coordinates. All I want to do is to pass these 2 values to my server when the submit button in the popover is hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are other more elegant methods, the simplest way is to simply create a hidden input field. And then before GET/POST use and onclick event handler to set the value to the X , Y values.

HTML:

```
<input type=hidden name="xValue"/>  
<input type=hidden name="yValue"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>  
 function submitxy(x , y){  
    document.form.xValue.value = x;   
    document.form.yValue.value = y;   
 }  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction! I actually use jQuery to change the input hidden. I used something like:      $("input[name='xValue']").val("30");